# Using PHPpowerpoint in MVC Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phppowerpoint

I'm trying to use PHPPowerPoint (which I downloaded from http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/26621); I downloaded the source files which also include both libraries and the test code for generating Powerpoints. It is working fine If I use it in web form application; howerver I have to use it in CodeIgniter MVC application, so I put the libraries folder which is called "classes" to "libraries" of the codeigniter framework and Im trying to use one of the sample codes (they provided to generate the Powerpoints) in my model; but after struggling for a couple of hours I could not fix the require paths which I get from the smaple code (01simple.php) and it gives me the following error:

> ```
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPPowerPoint.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> ```
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\application\libraries\PHPPowerpoint\Classes\PHPPowerpoint\Slide.php
>   on line 30

Could you please help me how I can use this phppowerpoint libraries in MVC CodeIgniter? I really appreciate if you can help me with the settings. Sorry if my question is ambiguous, please let me know and I will provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically looks like you are having issues with your paths.  I would check where you are requiring it, in relation to where the library actually exists on the server.  You likely just need to play around with your require statements.

Maybe this link will help out?
http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-258928.html

Comment: I added my attempt for debuging in a new comment; I really appreciate your help :)